# Should edits that "improve" formatting be accepted during review

Tags: discussion, review

I was reviewing an edit that I rejected because I think that it's just formatting the code to an alternate style. I would in the case below agree that edit is more in line with how **I**  think the code should be formatted, but I understand that there are different styles of coding and I should not impose on others.

So should I in the future accept these types of edits or should I keep rejecting them?

[image: Screenshot of the review in question]

Comment: If there is nothing else left to be improved than `approve` but if this is the only thing that has been improved but the text portion makes no sense than `reject`. *At least I go by those rules which is why I have rejected more than 50% of all suggested edits I have reviewed.* If the formatting really makes the code more readable and still compatible then why not approve (still make sure there is nothing else to improve in the post).